# Searching in scope for first name, last name or fullname in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started developing in Ruby on Rails and am trying to define a search scope in my User mode. With the following scope I am able to search for a user based on his first name or his last name:

```
  scope :_s, -> (s) {    
    where(
    'unaccent(LOWER(email)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))
    OR unaccent(LOWER(first_name)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))
    OR unaccent(LOWER(last_name)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))',
    "%#{s}%", "%#{s}%","%#{s}%") }
```

I can't get my scope up and running to search for the full name, I thought the following would work:

```
  scope :_s, -> (s) {
    select('(first_name || " " || last_name) as \'full_name\', *')  
    where(
    'unaccent(LOWER(email)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))
    OR unaccent(LOWER(first_name)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))
    OR unaccent(LOWER(last_name)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))
    OR unaccent(LOWER(full_name)) like unaccent(LOWER(?))',
    "%#{s}%", "%#{s}%","%#{s}%","%#{s}%") }
```

But this returns

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "full_name" does not exis

I understand that my database thinks that I am looking for a record in the database, but how can I tell it to look at the defined full_name above?

Comment: why are you not using `pg_search` gem?

Comment: This is the only search that I have, an extra gem is overkill (I think?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how SQL aliases work, the where clause doesn't know anything about the aliases defined in the select clause. Replace

```
unaccent(LOWER(full_name))
```

with

```
unaccent(LOWER(first_name || \' \' || last_name))
```

Comment: That returns: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column " " does not exist LINE 5: OR unaccent(LOWER(first_name || " " || last_name)) like ... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: Double-quotes are for column names. Use single-quotes for string values: `' '`.